# Selenium scroll into view with a twist Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image: The blue arrow is the scroll im trying to make scroll]

I am trying to scroll elements into view in order to be able to do stuff with them ..that would usually be done using scroll into view ..or actionchains but the scroll isnt on the window..its in the window. as in there is a seperate scroll bar within the window. the page does have a normal window scroll bar but scrolling with that doesn't not put the required elements into view.
so my question is ..is there a way to scroll the inner scroll bar down?

The blue arrow is the scroll im trying to make scroll

i know for a fact that scrolling with this stops my code from crashing as iv manually scrolled to bring the elements into view and it works but i need it to do it automatically.
note to be taken ..the screen is zoomed out slightly in order to show more elements ..this i think would work but if i have more elements within the Active trades bar then that technique would be obsolete.

The CSS selector  for the scrolling bar i want to move is here
 `driver1.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", driver1.find_element_by_css_selector("#mCSB_2_dragger_vertical > .mCSB_dragger_bar"));`

the

edit:
mustered up some code that gives an error

```
    scrollbar = str(driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mCSB_2_dragger_vertical']").get_attribute("style"))
    print(scrollbar)
    new_style = scrollbar.get_attribute('style').replace('top: 0px', 'top 200px')
    driver1.execute_script('arguments[6].setAttribute("style", "%s")' % new_style, scrollbar)
    print(scrollbar)
```

throws this error

```
 new_style = scrollbar.get_attribute('style').replace('top: 0px', 'top 200px')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

found this link that helped out ..ish

[How can I change an attribute value in the DOM using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172977/how-can-i-change-an-attribute-value-in-the-dom-using-selenium-and-python)

edit2:

tried multiple ways to try and achieve it ..i think 1 of the ways that i have here would work just needs tweaking

```
    #scrollbar = str(driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mCSB_2_dragger_vertical']").get_attribute("style"))
    #print(scrollbar)
    #new_style = driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mCSB_2_dragger_vertical']").get_attribute("style").replace('top: 0px', 'top: 200px')
    #driver1.execute_script('arguments[6].setAttribute("style", "%s")' % new_style, scrollbar)
    #print(scrollbar)
    element = driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mCSB_2_dragger_vertical']")
    #A = driver1.execute_script("argument[0]",element)
    driver1.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'top: 300px')", element)
    #A =driver1.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'top: 100px'", element)
    #print(A)
    #driver1.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('top:', 'top: 300px')", element)

    #div_elem = driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mCSB_2_dragger_vertical']")
    #print(div_elem.text)
    #new_style = div_elem.get_attribute('style').replace('top: 0px', 'top: 200px')
    #driver1.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("style", "%s")' % new_style, div_elem)
    #print(div_elem.text)
    #newvalue = "200px"
    #splitting = scrollbar.split(": ")
    #indextochange = str(splitting[6])
    #EntirenewAttribute = str(scrollbar.replace(indextochange,newvalue))
    #driver1.execute(scrollbar.replace(scrollbar,EntirenewAttribute))#EntirenewAttribute
    #driver1.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", scrollbar, top = "200")
    # print(scrollbar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the normal click() actions of selenium should handle the scrolling for you, even if you have inner scrollbars. If that does not work, you need to use `JS scrollIntoView`

Your attempt to use JS in this case is correct, but your selector seems to be too specific and not match the element you want.

Try to press F12 in your browser (will open the debug tools).

Then type that JS code in the console:

```
document.querySelector("#mCSB_2_dragger_vertical > .mCSB_dragger_bar")
```

That way you will see which element your selector actually matches. Then change it so that it matches the element you really want to have in your view.

Comment: so i did as you asked and managed to muster up some code ..its in the edit now

Comment: did argument 6 as the "top" is the 6th argument i think